# You touch me everyday

Tags: riddle

I am three.
One of me can make it a challenge to see.
One of me can be soft.. if I am not hard.
Normally, I am spherical, unless something touches me.
You touch me everyday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Water

I am three.

> I have three forms (vapor, liquid, ice).

One of me can make it a challenge to see.

> Vapor form.

One of me can be soft.. if I am not hard.

> Water in its frozen state can be soft as snow or hard as ice.

Normally, I am spherical, unless something touches me.

> In space, water is spherical.  Only when touched by gravity or a container does it take another form.

You touch me everyday.

> You wash you hands at least once a day, don't you?  Even if you don't, your lips touch water, even if it is Coca-cola.  Even breathing can count as touching water.

Comment: for some reason I had found the answer but I tried to make "snowball" fit into the "spherical" clue and it didn't really made any sense

Comment: "I am three" can also refer to the base elements- 2 Hydrogen, 1 Oxygen

Comment: There's also "soft [solution]" and "hard [solution]" as concepts

Comment: FYI Even under gravity water drops are spherical. Falling water does not form the classical 'teardrop' shape.